# how can I lock the excel file in SSIS import package

Tags: ssis

In my SSIS import package I need to lock the excel file to prevent the user overwritte the same file, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first verify whether the file is locked or not before proceeding for the data flow task to insert the data into the file .You can use a script component before the DFT and check whether the file is locked .

```
 try
   {
    using (Stream stream = new FileStream("Filename.txt", FileMode.Open))
          {
          }
  }
 catch
 {
   Raise an exception if the file is in use and wait for couple of sec before 
   you recheck the file
 }
```

The above code is not full proof as you need to further check for file existence and different file modes

Refer [this](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.in/2011/05/wait-until-file-is-unlocked.html) article

Comment: That is helpfull for me but my problem in this momeent is when the package is running the user can update the excel file and my process fail for the excel connection excel source fail... To prevent the user made a change or replace the file that I want to lock the file inside the package

Comment: Sadly there is no way you can achieve that in SSIS . But you can COPY the file to a location then perform the insert and again MOVE the file to your original location by setting the OVERWRITE value to True.This will make sure that users who have done any changes during the SSIS execution wont get saved as you are over writing the file with a new one

Comment: There is one more component which might be helpful to u.File Watcher Task http://www.sqlis.com/post/file-watcher-task.aspx